# is there a way to loop something in infinite speed and not every frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

So, if I'm checking for something in the enterframe event listener, and I want to check (if something happens) do this. But somehow checking every frame was too slow. Is there a way to check in infinite speed and not every frame, so that when it checks something, it instantly changes to that position?

Comment: If you want to instantly change the position, you'll need to directly tell your object to change position. What you might need to do to solve your problem is change the order of your code (e.g. put the change position code before a hitTest instead of after it). Hard to tell without any code to examine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please post concrete example code.

Comment: Indeed, without seeing what you are doing, it's difficult to give a good answer.   Though the short answer is no (to infinite speed, as that would lock your application and is called a for-loop), and yes (to being faster than the framerate) though if what are doing is display oriented there is little point in running faster than the framerate

Comment: Honestly, I wasn't looking to ask help for my code. I just wanted to see if there was a way to get a faster way of looping than the enter frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is no way to check something faster than once per frame, if you have your frame rate already at 60fps. `Timer` is limited to trigger at most 60 times per second, and this is the same speed you can get by setting `stage.frameRate` too. But, if you are checking, for example, the collision of something that flies very fast and an obstacle, which is before that obstacle in the current frame, and past it the next frame, you can use a derivative of [axis-aligned bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box) collision detection, and also transition collision detection [(a probable example is here)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95793/how-to-resolve-collision-between-a-dynamic-aabb-and-static-aabb/95795#95795), which is checking if the path intersects a bounding box in the time between two frames.

If you are checking for a process that depends on certain factors and time, and you can check its condition in this frame and the previous frame, you can interpolate that process between frames in a conventional enterframe listener and check if the condition you are seeking **might** happen in between, and if it might, you might check whether it **did** happen by interpolating at a smaller time intervals than a frame. Still, you'd better refrain from using `hitTest` in such interpolation, as this is very costly check, and you can receive faster negative results from AABB checks and other methods of optimizing collision detection.

Comment: Technically, you **can** check something faster than once per frame using a `Timer`.  Though as it would seem they want to do something with a display object's position, there is no gain in using a timer that ticks faster than the framerate (and the challenges that can come with that).  But as the question is quite vague on usage, it seems worth pointing out.

Comment: @LDMS Past Flash 10 (IIRC) timers no longer trigger their events faster than once per frame. In Flash 9 it was indeed possible.

Comment: do you have a source/documentation for this?  I ask because I had an interesting project a year or two ago that was very low framerate, and I had a timer running at about 3 times the framerate and the timer was definitely ticking 3 times faster than the enter frame event.

Comment: Oops, I was assuming the framerate is maxed (60fps) and then yes, timers can't tick faster than that. Sorry. Still, the main plot of the answer holds, if you want better accuracy than 60fps, do interpolation.

Comment: I totally agree that interpolation is the best option.  I just thought you may want to correct your first sentence to avoid confusion.